# How do I show the divider for the last row in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to make the divider for the last row appear so that the list "looks clean".

My `ListView` has been "included" in another XML layout.

I found that other posts show to use:

```
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

or

```
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
```

Neither work for me.  I know I have the right XML layout because I can set the divider color to RED, and it renders correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: no following answer solve or help your issue? please response

Answer (score 0):

You may define a drawable for the divider and add a view with background set to the divider drawable below list view .

Answer (score 0):

Add a line view below `ListView`:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_perent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:padding="your_padding"
    android:background="@color/your_color"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are Inflating a custom view , you can add the following at the bottom of your custom view XML :

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="4dp"
android:background="#000000">
</RelativeLayout>
```

this will make a layout 4dp heigh black in color making it look like a line 4dp wide.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately had to do the following:
1) Create a custom divider xml such as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <size android:height="1dip" />
        <solid android:color="@color/divider" />
    </shape>
```

2) Then add the following to my LinearLayout widget.

```
        android:divider="@drawable/custom_list_divider"
        android:showDividers="end"
```